# For $f(x)=x^4$, find its projection $f(x)^*\in P^2(-1,1)$ onto $W$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, approximation

> Consider the vector space $V=C[-1,1]$ and $W=P^2[-1,1]$. $V$ is an inner product space withe inner product $\langle f, g\rangle=\int_{-1}^1f(x)g(x)dx$. Consider a function $f(x)=x^4$ whcih is in $V$ but not in $W$. Find its projection $f^*$ onto $W$.

---

These are what I have so far:

Basis of $P^2(-1,1)=\{1,x,1-3x^2\}$, $f(x)-f^*(x)$ is orthogonal to the basis, so $\langle 1, f(x)-f^*(x)\rangle=\langle x, f(x)-f^*(x)\rangle=\langle 1-x^2, f(x)-f^*(x)\rangle=0$, I got
\begin{align*}
   \langle 1,f(x)-f^*(x)\rangle & =\int_{-1}^{1}1\cdot[x^4-(a+bx+cx^2)]\,dx=0\\
   \langle x,f(x)-f^*(x)\rangle & =\int_{-1}^{1}x\cdot[x^4-(a+bx+cx^2)]\,dx=0\\
   \langle 1-3x^2,f(x)-f^*(x)\rangle & =\int_{-1}^{1}(1-3x^2)\cdot[x^4-(a+bx+cx^2)]\,dx=0
   \end{align*}
            By solving the system above, we receive $f^*(x)=-3/35+6/7x^2$.

---

I am not sure this is right or not. Can someone check this solution?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, let me say that your approach works.

That said, you can save some effort when you take an orthogonal basis, because the coefficient of $p_k$ in the projection of $f$ is $\frac{\langle f,p_k \rangle}{\langle p_k,p_k \rangle}$ provided $p_k$ are orthogonal to each other. Thus with $f=x^4$ and the basis you chose you have the coefficients:

1: $\frac{\int_{-1}^1 x^4 dx}{\int_{-1}^1 1 dx} = \frac{1}{5}$.

x: $\frac{\int_{-1}^1 x^5 dx}{\int_{-1}^1 x^2 dx} = 0$.

$1-3x^2$: $\frac{\int_{-1}^1 x^4-3x^6 dx}{\int_{-1}^1 (1-3x^2)^2 dx} = \dots$ (you can do the integration)

Comment: I am not quite understand your second sentence.

Comment: @Simple The third sentence expresses all the content of the second sentence in this context.

Comment: Do you mind write your approach? I don't know how to do it with your suggestions.